# Toast showing up twice

Tags: java, android

I have a program that sends pre-defined text messages to a group of people at a push of a button. I have it working well but the problem I have is that when it sends the messages, it pops up with 2 toasts per message sent. Code:

```
package com.mfd.alerter;

//imports

public class homeScreen extends Activity {

//buttons

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //vars

    // Grab the time
    final Date anotherCurDate = new Date();  
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("km");  
    final String formattedTime = formatter.format(anotherCurDate);

    // Contacts
    final String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);

    // Start messages. Only 1 is given to shorten post
    callStructureFire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msgText = "MFD PAGE OUT:\nStructure Fire\nTimeout:"+formattedTime;
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                sendSMS(numbers[i], msgText);
            }
        }
    });

    //more call types. not important.
}

//---sends a SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String numbers, String message)
{           
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);


    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(numbers, null, message, sentPI, null);               
}  

//action bar stuff. not important.

}
```

More in detail: Lets say I send the text to 3 people, 6 toast messages will pop up saying "SMS Sent". How do I make it so only 3 will show up?

Also, Is there a way to maybe add a counter of the messages sent? Ex: "Message 1/10 sent", "Message 2/10 sent", etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to register the receiver only once and not every time you call sendSMS.
You get 6 Toasts with three sms messages because you have 3 BroadCastReceivers. So in the first run you get 1 Toast. In the second run you get 2 Toasts (the receiver that was registered in the first run is called, and the one in the second). In the third run all three receivers are called, so you get three more toasts. All in sum - 6 Toasts...

so I guess, you have to register only one receiver before the for loop where you call sendSMS, or if you want the registration in sendSMS, then you have to unregister at the end of the method.

I hope this helps,
cheers!

Comment: (I am new to programming Java/Android so bear with me on terms.) Can you show me what part you are talking about and a possible fix? I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: (After running a few quick tests) I do believe you are correct in your response though as each time i add a contact, it increases exponentially.

Comment: Don't have it completely resolved yet. Still trying to figure out how to stop looping the receiver.

Comment: ooo.. just take the registerReceiver method and the whole implementation of the BroadcastReceiver out of the sendSMS method and put it before callStructureFire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener().... This should do the job...

Comment: Thanks. That worked. It will be so much better knowing my phone wont be awake for 10 minutes so I don't accidentally bush another button lol.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really look at your code or asked myself why this happens but here's a trick to stop toasts show up twice:

Create a Toast instance using [makeToast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29), before showing it you call [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29), set your text and then call [show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show%28%29). This will dismiss the previous toast. You won't even notice that a toast is displayed twice.

That's a stupid workaround, but it works for me ;-)